# How to split string when the value changes in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, split

I have this string (I can't modify it)

```
"AAACCDEEB"
```

And I want to split it into an array when the value changes. So in this example I would have 5 arrays like this

```
[['A','A','A'], ['C','C'], ['D'],['E','E'], ['B']]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? What about `'AACCAA'`, would that become `[['A','A'],['C','C'],['A','A']]`

Comment: Please show your recent attempts to solve this yourself as in [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Comment: @evolutionxbox Yes

Comment: Where is this string stored (var)?
Why can't you modify if?
How would you know it has changed?
Why do you want to split it into an array + why only when (after) it changes?
What are you using the array for?
What have you tried?
Did you manage to split ANY array as in your wanting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should try

```
"AAACCDEEB".match(/(.)\1*/g)
```

It should give you ["AAA", "CC", "D", "EE", "B"]

It works with regex expression, this one :

```
/(.)\1*/g)
```

and matches any single char followed 0 or multiple times by the same character.

You could also see some documentations about regex expressions, it's very efficient on this type of situations!

If my answer help you, don't hesitate to accept it as an answer :)

Comment: This is great -- so useful

Answer (score 0):

So maybe it would be:

```
 var string = "AAACCDEEB";
 var strArray = [[], [], [], [], []];
for(var x = 0; x <= (strArray.length-1); x++){
var val1 = 'A';
var val2 = 'C';
var val3 = 'D';
var val4 = 'E'
var val5 = 'B';
for(var n = 0; string[x] == val1; n++){
strArray[0][n] = string[x];
}
for(var m = 0; string[x] == val2; m++){
strArray[1][m] = string[x];
}
for(var o = 0; string[x] == val3; o++){
strArray[2][o] = string[x];
}
for(var z = 0; string[x] == val4; z++){
strArray[3][z] = string[x];
}
for(var i = 0; string[x] == val5; i++){
strArray[4][i] = string[x];
}

}
document.write(strArray);
```

Tell me if it is helpful by accepting it!!